# Mean for grouped data when midpoints are unknown

Tags: distributions, estimation, mean, exponential-distribution

I have a dataset with disease frequency in age groups.

```
<1   <3   <5   <7   >=7 
14   19   15    3    10
```

And now, when actual data lost, I've been asked to assess the mean age. The problem that I don't know the midpoint for last interval ">=7".

How should I do it? Can I model the distribution of age and get the mean using formula?

I've splitted groups to be width of 1 age, from 0 to 7, and it seems that age have exponential distribution (like it should be in theory). But how to assess distr. parameters? I've assessed the median from groupped data using the formula [described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879052/how-to-find-mean-and-median-from-histogram):
$$Me = L_m + (\frac{n/2 -F_{m-1}}{f_m}) \cdot c = 2.737$$

After that I've calculated $\lambda$ using it like this: $\lambda = ln(2)/Me = 0.253$. Assessing $\lambda$ visually I've got pretty same value $0.23$. Here is the plot.

[image: The plot]

For me this distributions look almost equal except point 0, but which should I choose and why? Is it ok to use median to assess $\lambda$?

If so, is the next argument true?
I can get the estimate for upper bound of the last interval using 0.975 quantile. Use it to get the midpoint. And now calculate the mean using midpoints. How much it should be different? Doesn't midpoints introduce bias because data distributed exponentially?
Using distributions I've got: $4.348$ (for 1st), $3.949$ (2nd)
And using midpoints: $3.902$, $3.784$

Thanks for any help or correction.

Comment: Closely related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12490 (showing how to estimate parameters of a distribution based on binned data).  Could you explain how your plot is related to the data table? It shows ages in one-year bins rather than the two-year bins given in the table and it shows no age above 7 years.

Comment: @whuber, It's a histogram with density on vertical axis and frequency as area. I should merge bins, but don't know how to do it in ggplot, fixed by hand. There is no age >7 because I don't know the upper bound of group ">7". I've used this plot to assess distribution. If my argument about 0.975 quantile to estimate the upper bound is true, then the plot looks [like this](http://i.imgur.com/aVTIj1q.png). Because the variable is distributed exponentially, the left part of 2 year long bins should be greater, so it looks like to be true. I'll check the link, thanks.

Comment: The maximum likelihood approach explained in my answer in the linked thread will (a) work (easily) for exponential distributions and (b) applies without change even to infinite intervals.

Comment: @whuber thank you for the link, I've solved my problem using it, but what should I do with this question? Delete or point to your link in text?

Comment: I think that your question, which is well-formulated and -illustrated, adds value to our site.  I have therefore closed it as a "duplicate" of the thread you used to solve your problem, but would suggest that you not delete it.